# Relations between positive numbers in $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

Suppose $A,B,C,D$ are positive numbers in $[0,1]$.

Assume

$$
D\leq A+B
$$

$$
D\geq C
$$
$$
C\leq A
$$
$$
C\leq B
$$
Does this imply
$
D\leq A+B-C
$?

Comment: It implies: $0\leq A+B-C$

Comment: @STF -- Did you mean positive integers (as in your title)? Or real numbers between $0$ and $1$ inclusive?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! $A=B=\frac{1}{2}$, $D=1$ and $C=\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, given the constraints, the quantity

$$D-(A+B-C)$$

has minimum value $-2$ using

$$A=B=1\;\;\text{and}\;\;C=D=0$$

and maximum value $\large{\frac{1}{2}}$ using

$$A=B=C = \frac{1}{2}\;\;\text{and}\;\;D=1$$

Since the maximum value of $D-(A+B-C)\,$ is greater than $0$, the inequality

$$D \le A+B-C$$

is not forced to hold.